# Reporte de crystal report con dos recibos por pagina separados por una linea en el medio

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Estoy en el medio de un problema que me tiene casi colapsando.
Verán, necesito crear un reporte en crystal report (Visual Studio) que muestre dos recibos por página (ya lo logré) y que en medio de los dos recibos exista una línea, por ejemplo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como lo tengo actualmente, pero, resulta que la linea no se encuentra justo a la mitad ( Verticalmente ) de la página y eso de estar cambiando la posición de los elementos y estar probando las impresiones me esta agotando.

Mi pregunta sería, existe alguna manera de centrar el Objeto de Línea en el documento, independientemente de la posición de los demás objetos?

El top del objeto de linea debería quedar a 5.5 Pulgadas de una hoja tipo Carta.